# How to style overgrown bangs that won’t stay put?

Tags: hair

I have overgrown bangs that, when stretched, reach to the end of my nose. They curl into an S shape and won’t uncurl. I’ve tried brushing them out but they still stayed he same way. My bangs that usually hang on the side of my face. Is there a way to get them to be straight and style them in a different way?

Comment: If your aim is to have the hair straight - have you tried using [hair straighteners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_iron)?

Answer (score 2):

Mini Hair Tutorial: Each hair strand is extruded from its follicle as it grows much like toothpaste squeezed from a tube. As it grows, it will have a characteristic profile, in addition to colour, determined by your genetic composition. (Blame your parents.)

Hair is a kind of plastic and has similar characteristics. You can temporarily change the shape of the hair by using heat as you apply a bit of tension as wet hair dries and cools. It's a mechanical action called thermoforming that is used in shaping plastics. It's done every day when wet hair is wound around a hair curler and dried while held in position. Other factors affect the result. If the hair is allowed to dry and cool completely before being released from the curler 'mold,' the shape will hold longer than if released warm or still damp.

**Heavenly Hair Hack:**

You will need a round hair brush like this one:
[image: Round Hair Brush]
and a hair dryer.

Towel dry your hair after washing. Wind your hair around the brush by turning the handle of the brush and dry it while you gently pull (apply tension to) your hair. If your hair pulls free of the brush as you lightly pull, wind it up again and continue this until your bangs are completely dry and in the shape you wish. That's it.

Using a round motorized spinning brush as you apply heat is easier.
A round, motorized, spinning-brush hair dryer is the best way to go if you must do it yourself or if you do this often (as a hair stylist/for a living) to prevent shoulder bursitis - like this one:

[image: Spin Air Rotating Styler Hot Air Brush]

There are a few different models available.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to [Stan's answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/26413/26801):

To straighten your hair you'll want to use a **very big round brush**. They're usually available in the beauty section of convenient stores or in drug stores and don't cost very much. Try the biggest one you can find.

You'll need a blow dryer. If your model is adjustable, set it to medium heat and medium speed (at least I find it more comfortable than being wipped in the face by my own hair).

- Tilt your head forward so you can scoop up your bangs with the round brush. Rotate the brush slightly so it pulls your hair straight.
- Point the air flow from the blow drier directly at the brush and slowly move the brush away from your face.
- Blow the air from above and point the blow dryer away from your face to avoid tangles.
- Style first one half of your bang, the the other half.
- Repeat until your hair is dry.
- Don't stick your bang behind your ear right after drying or it will immediately curl up again.

[image]

If your hair starts curling again after a while, you can straighten it out again by blow drying it again as written above, even if the hair is dry. The heat alone is enough.

Comment: The hand drawing alone deserves a +1 :D